# where clause in inner join query

Tags: mysql, sql

please help me out regarding this query:

```
function viewServices($userpno)
{
    echo $userpno;

    $this->query = "
SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id, service.name AS servicename ,
       service.description AS servicedescription, employee.name AS employeename, employee.pic_path AS employeepicture,
       employee.pic_path 
FROM task where task.user_id = '$userpno' 
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.pno = task.employee_id
INNER JOIN user ON user.pno = task.user_id
INNER JOIN service ON service.service_id = task.service_id
";
}
```

The query works perfectly without:

```
WHERE task.user_id = '$userpno'
```

I have tried in this way also:

```
WHERE task.user_id = $userpno
```

But it doesn't work.

The error is:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\admin\classes\Task.php on line 22
```

Please quide me about how can I put WHERE clause.

Comment: Did you know what you're doing here is a potential SQL injection attack? You *must* send the userpno value through mysql_real_escape_string. See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

Comment: @François Beausoleil We don't know for sure where `$userpno` is coming from, so we can't say for certain. Perhaps this function is passed userIDs directly from another query result. But if its value in some way originates from user input, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->query = "SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id,
service.name AS servicename ,service.description AS servicedescription, 
employee.name AS employeename, employee.pic_path AS employeepicture,employee.pic_path
FROM task 
INNER JOIN employee  ON employee.pno = task.employee_id  
INNER JOIN user  ON user.pno = task.user_id 
INNER JOIN service  ON service.service_id = task.service_id 
where task.user_id = '$userpno'";
```

Answer (score 7):

WHERE clause goes at the end of the query

```
SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id, service.name AS servicename ,service.description AS servicedescription, employee.name AS employeename, employee.pic_path AS employeepicture,employee.pic_path
FROM task
INNER JOIN employee  ON employee.pno = task.employee_id 
INNER JOIN user  ON user.pno = task.user_id
INNER JOIN service  ON service.service_id = task.service_id 
where task.user_id = '$userpno'
```

Answer (score 3):

Query structure is: SELECT, FROM (joins here), WHERE

you had the WHERE too soon

```
$this->query = 
   "SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id, service.name AS servicename ,service.description AS servicedescription, employee.name AS employeename, employee.pic_path AS employeepicture,employee.pic_path 
    FROM task INNER JOIN employee  ON employee.pno = task.employee_id  INNER JOIN user  ON user.pno = task.user_id INNER JOIN service  ON service.service_id = task.service_id 
    WHERE task.user_id = '$userpno'";
```

Queries that run correctly return a resource, those that fail return `false`

Answer (score 2):

You have JOIN clauses after your WHERE clause. That's not valid, so your query is returning `false` because it failed.

For reference, parts of a SELECT query must be in the order/format as outlined in the docs here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html